# Jquery doesn't fire through .change

Tags: jquery, json

I got the following jquery code:

```
$('.sub').change(function(event) {
$.post( 'get_products.php', $("#products_search").serialize(),
  function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
  },
  'json'
);
});
```

and have fields like

```
<input type="text" name="lkj" id="lkj" class="sub" value="" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search keyword') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value ='Search keyword'}"  />
```

The form is like this:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" name="products_search" id="products_search">
```

The jquery ajax call however doesn't fire when i change a value in lkj.

Comment: Nothing unfortunately :(

Comment: Can you show the error in fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change event isn't triggered immediately for a type=text input field. It is triggered when the field loses focus. If the user never tabs out or clicks outside of the input field, then change will never fire.

This is different with checkboxes and radio buttons which do trigger the change event immediately

The input must also be present in the DOM before you bind any event listeners to it. If its injected dynamically then you can use

```
$('body').on('change', '.sub', function() {
  // your code goes here
});
```

Also, to ensure your code is being called after the DOM has loaded wrap it in

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Comment: I know, but even when i click outside nothing happens... @Mark

Comment: @Michael review your error console and also add a callback for errors.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame I checked the console but there's nothing. In the Network tab there's nothing also so I know the call isn't even made so there's not callback as well...

Comment: @Mark You mean something like this?
`$(".sub").bind("click", function(){
 $.post( 'get_products.php', $("#products_search").serialize(),
      function( data ) {
          console.log(data);
      },
   'json'
    );
  });`

Nomatter where i click, nothing happens.

Comment: @Michael yes but not 'click', use the 'change' event here as well.

Comment: @Michael Is the .sub element present in the DOM before you're adding an event listener (bind) to the change event for it?

Comment: It's loaded up in a seperate .js file. I'll add it at the end of the dom and see how that goes. @Mark

Comment: Are you not wrapping it in a $(function() {}) or $(document).ready(function(){}); ?

Comment: No, it's just there. I loaded it up at the end of the DOM and now it works, thanks man! I'll include it in a document.ready statement @Mark

Comment: No prob, I updated my answer to mention the document.ready as well. Glad it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this example with binding to `on('change')` event:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" name="products_search" id="products_search">
    <input type="text" name="lkj" class="sub" placeholder="Search keyword"  />
</form>​
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.sub').on('change', function(event){
        $.post( 
            'get_products.php', 
            $("#products_search").serialize(),
            function( data ) {
              console.log(data);
            },
            'json'
        );          
    });​
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the difference than of just using .change? I thought .change was a shorthand of the binding handler

Comment: It's mainstream. JQuery is recomend to use `on` method for all events like `change, click, hover, etc.`

Answer (score 0):

Try a keyup with a timeout:

```
$('.sub').keyup(function(event) {

    if( $(this).timeout ) clearTimeout( $(this).timeout );

    $(this).timeout = setTimeout(function(){

        alert('posting...');

        $.post( 'get_products.php', $("#products_search").serialize(),
            function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
            }, 'json'
        );

    },250);

});
```

Make sure you wrap it in `$(function() { ...  })`;

Comment: @ anonymous down voting is lame Thanks man, but the document also includes hidden fields, radio's etc. But i'll use your code for the textfield though :)